# How to Resolve Auto-counting by Pandas in a Numerical column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset I applied some manipulation towards, however afterwards, pandas is Auto-counting a ID number in the ID field:

```
       ID     Full Name           Work_Date Time Code Covered
0   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/25/2018 0:00 USD     No
1   111814  Bellverdere, John   11/26/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
2   111815  Bellverdere, John   11/26/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
3   111816  Bellverdere, John   11/26/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
4   111817  Bellverdere, John   11/27/2018 0:00 USD     No
5   111818  Bellverdere, John   11/27/2018 0:00 EUR     No
6   111819  Bellverdere, John   11/28/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
7   111820  Bellverdere, John   11/28/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
8   111821  Bellverdere, John   11/29/2018 0:00 USD     No
9   111822  Bellverdere, John   11/29/2018 0:00 USD     No
10  111823  Bellverdere, John   11/29/2018 0:00 USD     No
11  111824  Bellverdere, John   11/30/2018 0:00 USD     No
12  111825  Bellverdere, John   11/30/2018 0:00 USD     No
```

The real result should be:

```
       ID     Full Name           Work_Date Time Code Covered
0   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/25/2018 0:00 USD     No
1   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/26/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
2   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/26/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
3   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/26/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
4   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/27/2018 0:00 USD     No
5   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/27/2018 0:00 EUR     No
6   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/28/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
7   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/28/2018 0:00 BTC     Yes
8   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/29/2018 0:00 USD     No
9   111813  Bellverdere, John   11/29/2018 0:00 USD     No
10  111813  Bellverdere, John   11/29/2018 0:00 USD     No
11  111813  Bellverdere, John   11/30/2018 0:00 USD     No
12  111813  Bellverdere, John   11/30/2018 0:00 USD     No
```

The auto-counting stops when a new ID appears, but shouldn't be happening at all.

Thanks to all who can assist!

Edit to include my code beforehand:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"default-title.xlsx",skiprows=8)

df = df.fillna(method='ffill') 

df['Covered'] = np.where(df['Time Code'].eq('BTC')
                            .groupby(df['Work_Date'])
                            .transform('any'),    
                            'Yes', 'No')


df = df[~df.Work_Date.str.contains("Total:",na=False)]
```

Essentially MY ID field needs to remain as '111813', but pandas proceeds to autocount the numbers to a point (111813, 111814, 111815) in the ID field which is incorrect.  Is there a way to ensure the values in the ID field remain consistent (as in remain 111813).

Comment: What do you mean by `Auto-counting`? also can you post your original/input dataframe & the code you ran on it?

Comment: is not clear your question...

Comment: Sure let me edit the to input my code

Comment: My apologies, I updated with some more code and hopefully a better explanation, essentially my ID field needs to remain as '111813', but pandas proceeds to auto-count the numbers forward to a point (111813, 111814, 111815) in the ID field which is incorrect.  Is there a way to ensure the values in the ID field remain consistent (as in remain 111813).  When another ID number to a different name appears (say 145289) this does not happen.                  Thanks again.

Comment: Did your data appear that way right after you do `read_excel`? Add a `print` command and see?

Comment: Hey Quang Hoang, it did appear that way right after I performed  read_excel, the only time it does not is if I make the ‘ID’ column the index column in the read_excel portion, but of course then pandas will not recognize the index column when I export. Thanks again for your help.